# NodeJS knex Select Innerjoin multiple fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I'm trying to perform a select on several tables but, as a table returns several records, json is duplicating the other data of the other tables, I would like to know how to separate the urls and subcategory in sub records without duplicating the other fields.

```
    async find(req, res, next) {
    try {
        const { id } = req.params

        const cases = await connection('cases')
            .where('cases.id', id)
            .innerJoin('categorys', 'categorys.id', '=', 'cases.category')
            .innerJoin('companys', 'companys.id', '=', 'cases.company')
            .innerJoin('images', 'images.id_case', '=', 'cases.id')
            .innerJoin('case_subcategory', 'case_subcategory.cases', 'cases.id')
            .innerJoin('sub_categorys', 'sub_categorys.id', '=', 'case_subcategory.sub_category')
            .select('cases.*', 'sub_categorys.name as subcategory', 'images.url', 'categorys.name as category', 'companys.name as company')

        return res.json(cases)
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
},
```

Result:

[IMAGE RESULT OF SELECT INSOMNIA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiY8y.png)

Comment: Basic nature of SQL query results are that they are flat tables. When you join data with something to many relations the fields will be duplicated. To have nested results you need to make one query for each table where you need data and then add post processing where you organize rows logically under in object tree. Though many ORMs like objection.js can do that automatically for you, if you first tell what kind of relations queried table has.

Comment: I would like to resolve this with a query, there is no way to handle the data and return:
[link](https://imgur.com/Csiqu0X)
and add url 3, url 4, category 3, category 4 as the result of the query

Comment: Not really. If you are using joins there will be duplicate fields. You could do subquery + conversion or result to JSON type of column (if your DB supports it), but that is quite hacky and inconvenient if there are more queries needing nested results.